# ClassCastException occured while deploying domain folder directly in Oracle weblogic 12.1.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

**what is the main different is deploying a WAR file and deploy domain folder directly in web application?**

I have deployed a web application in to **weblogic 12.1.2**  as a **WAR** file it work fine. But when i try to deploy same application as a **domain folder directly** I'm getting the following error.

**java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicApplicationBeanImpl cannot be cast to weblogic.j2ee.descriptor.wl.WeblogicWebAppBean**

I even fixed name space issue in weblogic-application.xml, also i checked duplicating element in weblogic-application.xml, I can't find any duplicate element in it. Can some one help me to solve this issue? Many Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "domain folder directly"? Are you talking about an exploded war file? Are you talking about the `autodeploy` dir? Are you asking about `stage` vs `nostage`? This question is confusing in it's current form.

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing Name is missing domain folder directly is an exploded war file. It help developers to do hot fix,

Comment: Can you post the full trace? It seems like it should work exactly the same... How are you targeting the exploded deployment (assuming you are using nostage)?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Maven to build both the WAR and EAR files. From there you should deploy the .ear file to Weblogic with no issues. Make sure your region properties are set correctly as well.